# Float and Vertical Align

Tags: html-table, css-float, vertical-alignment

I have a table with dynamic database (php and mysql loop) with image and text (name of image).
Within the TD I use float left to the image to make the text to the right, and also using margin-right to image. But now I want the text align to the bottom of TD. How to make the code?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img style="float:left; margin-right:12px;" src="pic.png">
text text... .( vertical-align:bottom )
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
<td valign="bottom">sumthere here</td>
```

I usually works for me.. also try to avoid unnecessary floats and margins. If you place  first, your image will always be placed before text.

Hope it help :)

Comment: That's not work. I just found method in using display: inline-block. And it's work. Thank you.